# jQuery draggable selector not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-draggable

i want to drag and drop my specifies elements but draggable selector not working well.

```
        $("#lessonTeacher p").draggable({
                revert: true,
                helper: 'clone',
                containment: "#timeTable"
        });
```

In the lessonTeacher div has many 'p' HTML tags. And i want to drag the 'p' items. But this code didn't work.

Comment: $(".lessonTeacher p") would work ... $('#id') work only one time for one element

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>

    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```